# How to make a proc freq table for one variable given another variable

Tags: sas, proc

I need to make a proc freq levels table for a variable "type", but only for entries that are ' USA ' under the "place_of_origin" variable.

Right now I'm doing

```
proc freq data=CarsVROOM nlevels;
tables type;
run;
```

and it shows me the freq table for all the "Type"s, but I want to see the freq table for all the "Type"s only for ' USA ' objects. 
What options do I add to the tables statement?
Thanks :)

Comment: Show some sample data exhibiting the different values of `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to have where statement?

```
proc freq data=CarsVROOM nlevels;
  where type = 'USA';
  tables type;
run;
```